# Немного или не много

Tags: частица-не

"Немного нас, таких смешливых" или "Не много нас таких смешливых" - как правильно?
Я склоняюсь к первому варианту, ведь хотя есть противопоставление, союза "а" здесь нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысловой оттенок этого выражения ("мало", либо подразумеваемое отрицание противоположного "много") должен содержаться в контексте, поскольку в устной форме варианты самого выражения не различаются.

Немного нас, таких смешливых, но рассмешим всех остальных.
(нас мало, но мы в тельняшках)

Не много нас таких смешливых - ошибся комик из Москвы.
(понадеялся на смешливое большинство в нашей аудитории)

Answer (score 2):

Если в значении "мало", то слитно, если отрицает, что много, то раздельно - на усмотрение автора. Мне ближе раздельно.